# JQuery prevent Doubleclick and unexpected behavior on Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I have the following JQuery driven carousel - the code for that is:

```
$('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent, opacity:0},600,function(){
            /* when the animation finishes use the if statement again, and  make an illusion
            of infinity by changing place of last or first item*/
            if(where == 'left'){
                //...and if it slided to left we put the last item before  the first item
                $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul  li:last'));
            }else{
                //...and if it slided to right we put the first item after the last item
                $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));
            }

            //...and then just get back the default left indent
            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-300px'});
 });
```

I'd like to prevent the ability to doubleclick the button and also, disable clicking all together while the #carousel_ul is animating and then re-enable the button on completion of the animation. Here is a roughed together codepen with all of the code:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epVObx (please excuse the placeholder images) Also, the relevant code begins at the comment in the JQuery: //FUNCTIONS BELOW

Thanks in advance for any guidance -

Comment: codepen example seems to work as you describe how you want it to work. When i double click it still only moves by one and when you click while it's moving it has no effect. What exactly do you mean by disable clicking?

Comment: Well for the code pen is only an example - in my particular unit I'm having it move two carousel elements separately - Basically, I want the button active when the unit is not being interacted with, and then once clicked, I want the two arrow buttons disabled until the animation finishes. In Javascript I would of had a removeEventListener at the start of  the animation function, and then an addEventListener at the completion of the animation. I'd also have used a  (for example) arrowLeft.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });